# Overlaying Two Images in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to overlay two images in VB.NET. These two pictures are contained in a PictureBox, `PictureBox1` and `PictureBox2`, with `PictureBox1` overlaying `PictureBox2`. Both images contained both PictureBoxes   I tried putting them on top of each other, but the transparency doesn't work. I also searched online for solutions, and one user pointed out to use the code:

`PictureBox2.Parent = PictureBox1`.

I attempted that solution, but with undesired results as shown below. (context shown after pictures)
[image: Unexpected Results]

[image]
[image: Both pictures seperated]

**First Picture: What results I got**
**Second Picture: What I want to get**
**Third Picture: Both Pictures**

I would like to find a way to overlay them, so I get the expected results. (The second picture). Is there a efficient way to do that, without having to go through the hassle of saving or having to create a new one (Because the pictures are updated every second)?

Comment: You can draw the second Image over the original one or on the PictureBox surface. Its pretty fast, it takes only a few ms. This, of course, unless you want to be able to move the overlay Control, dragging it with a Mouse. I don't know how you got that all-blue result overlapping two PictureBoxes, it's peculiar :).

Comment: @Jimi, thanks again. Could you please provide me with some code to do that? Thanks.

Comment: It's time to do some research. GDI+ is the technology you will be using and that is implemented in VB via the `Graphics` class. If you will be drawing on the `PictureBox` control you will do so in its `Paint` event handler, using the `Graphics` object provided. Even if you see it done in examples, DO NOT call `CreateGraphics`.